# How can I use SFDX with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, automation, salesforce, cypress, jsforce

I'm currently able to connect my salesforce inside of my cypress folder. The problem is that I'm not able to use both tools inside of a spec file. Also, I'm trying to use jsforce, but I don't have any idea of how to do an integration with cypress.

Does anyone have a good idea to do this?

Example:

```
const jsforce = require('jsforce');
require('dotenv').config()

const {SF_LOGIN_URL, USER_NAME, PASSWORD, SECURITY_TOKEN} = process.env
const conn = new jsforce.Connection({
    loginUrl: SF_LOGIN_URL
})

conn.login(USER_NAME, PASSWORD+SECURITY_TOKEN, (err, userInfo)=>{
    if(err){
        console.error(err)
    } 

    conn.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity', function(err, opportunity){
        if(err){ return console.error(err);}
        console.log(opportunity.records)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the [JSForce page](https://jsforce.github.io/), the code you've used is under the **Node.js** tab.

Anything that requires Node to run must be put into a [task](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task), so off the top of my head

**/cypress/plugins/index.js**

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    loginJSForce() {

      const jsforce = require('jsforce');
      require('dotenv').config();

      const {SF_LOGIN_URL, USER_NAME, PASSWORD, SECURITY_TOKEN} = process.env;
      const conn = new jsforce.Connection({
        loginUrl: SF_LOGIN_URL
      })

      conn.login(USER_NAME, PASSWORD+SECURITY_TOKEN, (err, userInfo) => {

        if (err) {
          console.error(err)
        } 

        conn.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity', (err, opportunity) => {
          if (err) { 
            return console.error(err); 
          }
          console.log(opportunity.records)
        });
      });

      return null
    },
  })
}
```

**Test**

```js
cy.task('loginJSForce');
```

I'm guessing you want to run some assertions against `opportunity.records` in the test, in which case you need at minimum to return them (instead of `return null`).

Based on this example [Return number of files in the folder](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Return-number-of-files-in-the-folder), that needs a Promise and might look like this

**/cypress/plugins/index.js**

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    loginJSForce() {

      const jsforce = require('jsforce');
      require('dotenv').config();

      const {SF_LOGIN_URL, USER_NAME, PASSWORD, SECURITY_TOKEN} = process.env;
      const conn = new jsforce.Connection({ loginUrl: SF_LOGIN_URL });

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        conn.login(USER_NAME, PASSWORD+SECURITY_TOKEN, (err, userInfo) => {

          if (err) {
            return reject(err);
          } 

          conn.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity', (err, opportunity) => {
            if (err) { 
              return reject(err);
            }

            return resolve(opportunity.records)
          })
        })
      })
    },
  })
}
```

**Test**

```js
cy.task('loginJSForce')
  .then(records => console.log(records));
```

There's some things in the example that are not consistent, for example `return reject(err)` but no return on `resolve(files.length)`. I'd expect them to be treated the same.

You can try out both with and without `return` on a working system, see which way works.

---

You could also try to adapt the code on the **Web Browser** tab to run in the test script, but since you use `dotenv` and `process.env` you probably still need a task to access those env variables.